Query mysql JSON field without know index
I have installed MySql 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 - (Ubuntu).
I have a table named vendas_pendentes with a field named venda type JSON
I using a query to search for a key named order_reference like this:
select * from vendas_pendentes where venda->"$.data.items[*].order_reference" ='171972786245566' 

And it returns nothing, but when I replace [*] for [102] I get the line.
I am new to the json field in mysql. How can I query the database without knowing the "index number" inside items?
Many thanks!

venda->"$.data.items[*].order_reference" returns JSON array. You try to compare it with given string literal which is obviously FALSE.
You must test against your referential value using some searching function. See Functions That Search JSON Values
For example, use MEMBER OF (not optimal):
CREATE TABLE test (val JSON)
SELECT '{"x":[{"y":1,"z":2},{"y":11,"z":22}]}' val UNION ALL
SELECT '{"x":[{"y":1,"z":2},{"y":111,"z":222}]}';

SELECT CAST(val AS CHAR),
       val->'$.x[*].y',
       11 MEMBER OF(val->'$.x[*].y')
FROM test;




CAST(val AS CHAR)
val->'$.x[*].y'
11 MEMBER OF(val->'$.x[*].y')




{"x": [{"y": 1, "z": 2}, {"y": 11, "z": 22}]}
[1, 11]
1


{"x": [{"y": 1, "z": 2}, {"y": 111, "z": 222}]}
[1, 111]
0



fiddle
